# Iterating through a ViewBag list in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a dropdown list (ViewBag) of items and I want to extract the last item. How can I do that in my razor view?

Also, is there a way to find the index of a specific item in the ViewBag?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Yes if you are storing a list of items in a viewbag.. then you can iterate on it using normal foreach loop on your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming **Items** as your ViewBag property, you need to do following to get last item:

```
var lastItem = ViewBag.Items[ ViewBag.Items.Count-1];
```